# Instantiating parent or childclass depending on a parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a class Employee and a childclass Manager with an additional field bonus. I´d like to instantiate either the parent or the childclass depending on a parameter like so:

```
public static <T extends Employee> instantiateBasedOnVersion(int version) {
        if(version > 2) {
            Manager employee = new Manager();
            employee.setBonus(3000);
        } else {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
        }

        employee.setSalary(3000);

        return employee;

}
```

If I try to get rid of the generic and simply use Employee as a return value I can´t use the method setBonus, as it is a method of the child class.

```
public static Employee instantiateBasedOnVersion(int version) {
        Employee employee;
        
        if(version > 2) {
            employee = new Manager();
            employee.setBonus(3000); // does not work
        } else {
            employee = new Employee();
        }

        employee.setSalary(3000);

        return employee;

}
```

I already figured out that this does not work as I need to declare the object beforehand. So I tried:

```
public static <T extends Employee> instantiateBasedOnVersion(int version) {
    
        T employee;
        
        if(version > 2) {
            Manager employee = new Manager();
            employee.setBonus(3000);
        } else {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
        }

        employee.setSalary(3000);

        return employee;
}
```

But doing this results in the error

```
incompatible types: Manager cannot be converted to T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Employee declared in method <T>instantiateBasedOnVersion(int)
```

Is there another good way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't use generics for this, this looks like a simple Factory pattern.

Comment: Any reason not to just return `Employee` and get rid of the type parameter?

Comment: @ernest_k, I think this is what sittsering suggested. But if I do this, then I can´t use the setBonus-method anymore

Comment: It's not. Your second code block is what I'm suggesting. You can use `((Manager)employee).setBonus(3000);` for the line where you have `// does not work`. That's an unrelated problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply do something like this?

```java
public static Employee instantiateBasedOnVersion(int version) {    
    Employee employee;
    if(version > 2) {
        // create a local Manager variable
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        // set the bonus
        manager.setBonus(3000);
        // assign it to the outer variable
        employee = manager;
    } else {
        employee = new Employee();
    }
    employee.setSalary(3000);
    return employee;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe like this?

```
Employee employee;
        
if(version > 2) {
   employee = new Manager();
   employee.setBonus(3000);
   } 
else {
   employee = new Employee();
}

employee.setSalary(3000);
```

Comment: I tried this and now I can´t use the setBonus-method anymore...